# improperly configured app in settings.py of django

Tags: django

Tying to register my djano app in the settings section of my django project. but when i run the server i am getting an error in the terminal.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'site1app.apps' does not contain a class 'Site1appConfig'. Choices are: 'Site1AppConfig'.
```

I dont know what's going wrong as i just added it to the list of installed apps in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'site1app.apps.Site1appConfig',

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a miss on the capitalization for your class

Change:

```
'site1app.apps.Site1appConfig'
```

To:

```
'site1app.apps.Site1AppConfig'
```